# How to allow a port in Windows Firewall?

Tags: firewall, port-forwarding

I'm running a server in Firefox ([POW](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3002)) on Windows Vista and I want to access it from another computer. So, I need to allow connections to it through port 6670. How can I allow there connections? And what URL should I use to connect to it?

Comment: what version of windows? by "another computer" do you mean another pc on the same network, or another PC across the internet?

Comment: vista, and any other computer on the internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to the Windows firewall in **Control Panel**, simply open it and navigate to the **Exceptions Tab**, then click **Add Port**:

[image]

As far as I know this is the same on Vista once you navigate the firewall shortcut in Control Panel:

[image]

The default scope is the entire internet so all you need to do is input a port number, the name does not matter but I'd make it something obvious so you can remove it later. You can change this to be your local network only. If you want remote computers to access this, you will need to forward incoming requests on port 6670 and point them to your local computer which is also listening on that port.

Comment: how do i forward requests? or is that automatic?

Comment: and how do i access it from another computer?